# Issue with cyrillic characters in razor engine

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, outlook, razorengine

Please Help, I am having a problem with cyrillic characters in my email notificatons for asp.net-mvc app, which incorrectly displays in outlook. I send messages using SmtpClient, to create the messages using razor engine(I've got a few templates for different types of messages). I'm already added meta tag with charset utf-8 for my templates, also added

```
message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
message.HeadersEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
message.BodyTransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.EightBit;
```

for my message object(insrance of MailMessage class), but the problem remained. On web interfaces message looks fine, this issue appears only in outlook.
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe change the font in Outlook / Set the font in mai?

Comment: Can you show an example what you have on input and what you can see in output? I.e. what "привет" gets converted into? If you can provide hexdump, even better.

Comment: @mvp this text should be "дек 27 16:00 - 04:00", but I get "п╢п╣п╨ 27 16:00 - 04:00".

Comment: Apparently, you did not set all headers in your outgoing email to use `UTF-8` throughout, or Outlook prefers to use KOI8-R regardless of headers. According to http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/ , text `п╢п╣п╨` is `KOI8-R` representation of string `дек` in `UTF-8` encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem, and the resolution was to save the code/view files in which you are setting the texts in UTF-8 encoding.